# BeautifulSoup's find method returns Tag item, but call string get 'NoneType' Error

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I am just start learning python and bs4. And I am trying to parse a html page looks like this:

```
....
<p class="result-info">
    <span class="result-meta">
        <span class="result-price">$1895</span>
        <span class="result-hood"> address1 </span>
    </span>
    ....
```

My python code is as below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(allResponse.content)
    resultInfoTags = soup.find_all("p", class_="result-info")
    infoList = []
    for infoTag in resultInfoTags:
        infoDS = {}
        infoDS['detail_link'] = infoTag.find("a")['href']
        for metaData in infoTag.find_all("span", class_="result-meta"):
            firstSpan = metaData.find("span");
            infoDS['price'] = firstSpan.string
            lala = metaData.find("span", class_="result-hood")
            infoDS['area'] = lala.string
        infoList.append(infoDS)
```

The Error happens on the line `infoDS['area'] = lala.string`. It complains

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'`

But when I print type(lala), it shows that lala is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. When I print lala itself, it shows the whole tag text

`<span class="result-hood"> (address1)</span>`

I am confused because I am using same idea to get firstSpan and it doesn't have any problem to output the right string $1895. But it doesn't work for lala...I've spent a couple of hours to desperately investigate and search online but haven't found anything helpful...

Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: post all html code, please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem with your code, but I think the way you are actually getting the data from the classes is wrong. Normally when I use beautiful soup to find a specific class, I use a different method then you have. For example, I would use the following method: `variable = soup.find(attrs={"class": class_name_here})`followed by `variable = variable.getText()`.

Therefore in your case try the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(allResponse.content)
resultInfoTags = soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"result-info"})
infoList = []
for infoTag in resultInfoTags:
    infoDS = {}
    infoDS['detail_link'] = infoTag.find('a', href=True)
    for metaData in infoTag.find_all(attrs={"class":"result-meta"}):
        firstSpan = metaData.find(attrs={"class":"result-price"})
        infoDS['price'] = firstSpan.getText()
        lala = metaData.find(attrs={"class":"result-hood"})
        infoDS['area'] = lala.getText()
    infoList.append(infoDS)
```

Again, I'm not certain if this is what is going on in your program so let me know if not.

Comment: It doesn't work. I replace `metaData.find("span", class_="result-hood")` to your format `find(attrs={"class":"result-hood"})` it still complains `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'`... Our different implementation should work the same way. I learned the `class_` format from bs4's official website

Answer (score 0):

I luckily figured it out by tons of experiments today. If you met the same problem, add a non check `if lala is not None` before the line `infoDS['area'] = lala.getText()` solve the problem.
Although a none check do make sense there, I still don't know why whether there is a none check would affect the code if there is an actual value with `lala`. If you happen to know why, please leave a solution / explanation here. Much appreciate!